# Writing to a .txt file (UTF-8), python

Tags: python, save

I want to save the output (`contents`) to a file (saving it in UTF-8). The file shouldn't be overwritten, it should be saved as a new file - e.g. `file2.txt` 
So, I fists open a `file.txt`, encode it in UTF-8, do some stuff and then wanna save it to `file2.txt` in UTF-8. How do I do this?

```
import codecs
def openfile(filename):
    with codecs.open(filename, encoding="UTF-8") as F:
        contents = F.read()
        ...
```

Comment: "The file shouldn't be overwritten".  Why is there only one open if you are reading one file and writing a new file?

Comment: because this is an unfinished code. ...

Comment: "because this is an unfinished code"?  What?  "unfinished" isn't a good explanation for the mismatch between your requirements and your code.  Why is there only one open?  Please fix your code to match your requirements a little better.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The short way:

```
file('file2.txt','w').write( file('file.txt').read().encode('utf-8') )
```

The long way:

```
data = file('file.txt').read()
... process data ...
data = data.encode('utf-8')
file('file2.txt','w').write( data )
```

And using 'codecs' explicitly:

```
codecs.getwriter('utf-8')(file('/tmp/bla3','w')).write(data)
```

Comment: the file 'file2.txt' when opened in notepad isn't utf-8 encoded, probably because I decoded the data using codecs (import codecs) and when saving it to a file a use a different way as you suggested (using encode method). THe question is how do I encode it using codecs?

Comment: @Gusto - I added a separate method, although it's completely equivalent. How can you see in notepad that a file is not utf-8 encoded? notepad actually does the decoding for you.

Comment: I can see it because the Cyrillic characters are not properly   displayed, I have to decode it manually using the notepad encoder.
P.S. Using Notepad ++

Answer (score 11):

I like to separate concerns in situations like this - I think it really makes the code cleaner, easier to maintain, and can be more efficient.

Here you've 3 concerns: reading a UTF-8 file, processing the lines, and writing a UTF-8 file. Assuming your processing is line-based, this works perfectly in Python, since opening and iterating over lines of a file is built in to the language. As well as being clearer, this is more efficient too since it allows you process huge files that don't fit into memory. Finally, it gives you a great way to test your code - because processing is separated from file io it lets you write unit tests, or even just run the processing code on example text and manually review the output without fiddling around with files.

I'm converting the lines to upper case for the purposes of example - presumably your processing will be more interesting. I like using yield here - it makes it easy for the processing to remove or insert extra lines although that's not being used in my trivial example.

```
def process(lines):
    for line in lines:
        yield line.upper()

with codecs.open(file1, 'r', 'utf-8') as infile:
    with codecs.open(file2, 'w', 'utf-8') as outfile:
        for line in process(infile):
            outfile.write(line)
```

Answer (score 2):

Open a second file. Use [`contextlib.nested()`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.6/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.nested) if need be. Use [`shutil.copyfileobj()`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj) to copy the contents.